# PHP не отправляет запрос к БД

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Есть база данных, в ней 2 таблицы. На 1 странице идет взаимодействие с 1 таблицей, а на другой - со 2 таблицей. Но прикол в том, что на 1ой странице все работает, а на 2 странице ничего не происходит. Структура одна и та же, что там, что там, только меняются столбцы в таблице и переменные. При вводе через sql напрямую, записи появляются в таблице, а через форму - нет (а в 1ом случае все работает). Вот код:

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect('$1', '$2', '$3', '$4');
 if (!$connect) {
        die('Error connect to DataBase'); 
    }
$email1 = $_POST['email']; //полученное из формы name=email
$mess = $_POST['message']; //полученное из формы name=message
$time1 = date('Y/m/d H/m/s');

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `support`(`id`, `email`, `time`, `message`) VALUES (NULL,'$email1','$time1','$mess')");
```

Такое ощущение, будто он не подключился к базе, но ошибка то не вылезает. Что скажете?

Comment: Во-первых, адекватно называть переменные надо (а не $date1), во-вторых, Что мешает добавить проверку? `if ( !mysqli_query(...) ) { var_dump( mysqli_error($connect) ); }`

Comment: `  $connect = mysqli_connect('$1', '$2', '$3', '$4');          if (!$connect) {
        die('Error connect to DataBase'); 
    }`

Comment: Такая проверка у меня была

Comment: Я сижу с этой проблемой долго уже и, перечитав книжги, что есть, все равно не поняла, что же не так.

Comment: В этом коде неправильно примерно всё. Начиная с кода подключения и заканчивая кодом запроса. По ссылке выше есть рабочий пример. Главное без ошибок написать параметры подключения. Потому что сейчас тут ах ДВЕ ошибки: во-первых, переменные в РНР не могут начинаться с цифры, а во-вторых, в кавычках переменные не пишут. Надо определиться, что мы пишем - если строки, то в кавычках, если переменные - то без кавычек